# Disabling high dpi settings for java swing when building an exe

Tags: java, swing, launch4j, highdpi

I'm trying to make a java swing application which will be distributed to other computers. I am using launch4j to build the .jar file into an .exe file and want to disable high dpi settings. I have tried using the arguments

> -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=false

and

> -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0

however neither worked when running on another PC. I also tried creating a wrapper manifest with these settings but that didn't work either. I was wondering if there was a way of enforcing the high-DPI settings to be disabled on all PC's, whether it can be enabled in the IDE or in launch4j or something else.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? [Is it possible to disable Windows DPI scaling from within java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824996/java-is-it-possible-to-disable-windows-dpi-scaling-from-within-java)

Comment: unfortunately not because it seems to only work for JavaFX and not Swing, thank you though.