# Poor graphics with openJDK15 compared to JRE 1.8 SE

Tags: java, graphics, awt

Below are images produced with code from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_dip/java_buffered_image.htm.

The one on the left is compiled/ran with JRE 1.8 SE and on the right with OpenJDK 15. You can see the difference in quality as 1.8 is much sharper.

Images of 2 versions:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5xAU.png]

Does anyone know of a reason of a fix with 15? Is it just the nature of OpenJDK?

Thanks!

Comment: looks like you have scaling on the second version.

Comment: It's the exact same code I ran in 2 different installs. The openJDK seems bigger in all ways.

Comment: Neither.  Since Java 9, Java graphics takes Windows scaling into account.  I'm guessing that you have Windows scaling at 125 or 150 percent.  Check out this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824996/java-is-it-possible-to-disable-windows-dpi-scaling-from-within-java).

Comment: Ahhhhh, yes, reducing it to 100% in Windows took care of the issues, but I can't depend on other users doing that. I'm unable to find the setting in Eclipse yet.... Thank!!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64600797/131872 for a couple of ways to control the scaling.

Comment: Excellent, thank you @camickr.