# Windows 10, how to run java swing app unscaled, with 1:1 pixel

Tags: java, swing

On previous windows systems (and till some point also in Win10) any java swing app have a 1:1 pixel matching with display.

Now when I run the app with JFrame size 1920x1080 on 1920x1080 monitor, it looks like it is about 2/3 of the screen size. It looks like all the application GUI is squized (by downscaling) to fit into 2/3 of the display reslution. This makes everything looks awful.

Now any swing app is scaled down, and the pixels aren't anymore 1:1, this makes the cleartype text look awful, as well as other parts of the GUI, in many cases this render the GUI too small to be usable.

I need to run this app on clients computers, the GUI needs to be appealing, it would be best if I could do it without the need to manually change something in their operating systems.

How could I fix it?
Is there a way to tell the javaVM|win10 to not scale a particular java application?

Comment: Were there Microsoft updates? Maybe you can track it down to one specific update and find out what exactly it did to cause this? Does this only affect Swing GUI Applications?

Comment: @Fildor yes, there were updates, but I need to have this app run well on my clients computers, I can't advice all of them to uninstall win10 updates.

Comment: You could try to start the Swing application using `-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=false` or try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555401/java-disable-dpi-aware-not-working or this: http://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display

Comment: It doesn't change anything if I add to the VM arguments -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=false or -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true

Comment: I didn't mean to uninstall updates. Just track it down to maybe get to a solution. I am sure that the key to fixing it is to find out why it happens.

Comment: That's why I ask here.