# JavaFX font sizes are huge in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse, javafx, rcp, e4, efxclipse

I'm working on an RCP application that includes both Swing and JavaFX elements. The application needs to be compiled using Java 8, which results in the Swing elements not scaling on a high-DPI screen according to the text-size.

Using the [external manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555401/java-disable-dpi-aware-not-working/39372897#39372897), I'm correctly able to get the application work where both the Swing and JavaFX elements are scaled correctly, albeit a little blurry, on a high-DPI screen.

However, if I disable the external manifest, and look at just the JavaFX elements, the font-sizes are now gigantic. If I open the same JavaFX UI outside the RCP context, the fonts are correctly scaled.

**Anyone know how the scaling for JavaFX UI fonts can be fixed for RCP applications in high-DPI environments?**

Below are screenshots illustrating the issue:

**Outside RCP, no external manifest**
[image: Outside RCP, no external manifest]

**In RCP, WITH external manifest**
[image: In RCP, WITH external manifest]

**In RCP, WITHOUT external manifest**
[image: In RCP, WITHOUT external manifest]