# Set a JAVA_OPT parameter to "Override high DPI scaling behavior" in Windows10/Java8

Tags: java, java-8, windows-10, dpi, java-opts

Does anyone know if you can pass a **JAVA_OPT** parameter that will "*Override high DPI scaling behavior*" in Windows 10 with Java8?

***NOTE***: I do not want to use a registry setting change.

Below is the setting done manually on the java.exe

[java.exe properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKytZ.jpg)

Comment: [Duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/1230346/overriding-high-dpi-scaling-from-the-command-line/1230356)

Comment: did you see this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555401/java-disable-dpi-aware-not-working/39372897#39372897

Comment: I am looking for a Command-line argument, not a registry change.

Comment: That command line argument is in the question, right?

Comment: @NickL - I want command-line not registry

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "command line argument" in this context, but if you mean a JVM argument, then the answer is no. A JVM argument couldn't set an OS-level setting on how to run a an application process.

If you just want to set this configuration from the command line instead of having to do it from a UI, you could do it from a batch script [as described here](https://superuser.com/questions/1230346/overriding-high-dpi-scaling-from-the-command-line/1230356).

Comment: let me be clear by _command line_ I mean by using a **JAVA_OPT** argument with my start scripts.

Comment: No, like I said, this has nothing to do with Java or the JVM at all. This is an OS-level setting that tells Windows how to execute the process. The way the OS decides whether to use this mode is based on a registry setting (AFAIK). So, you'll have to set the registry value. You can do it from a script on the command line as I've linked to. If there is an alternative way to do this, it will likely have nothing to do with Java or the JVM.