# Java 16 app : ignore windows zoom/scaling

Tags: swt, manifest, java-16

i develop a java16 app, and i need to make it dpi/scale/zoom independant for the users, meaning whatever the windows parameters they choose (100%, 125%, 150% often recommended on laptops, also it can be launched through remote desktop session) the app will launch as I designed it, i.e. 100%

I use a bundled jre (if that's an important detail)

can I do this ? I tried a lot of things, none of them working

For exemple tried the manifest solution given here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39372897/4571555

does not work for me. seems like it's an 'old' solution, now java16 running in 64bits, I do not know if it could be a reason for the manifest not doing anything...

if you guys have any other lead, I appreciate it !

edit : large use of SWT in that application

Comment: So your application uses AWT, Swing, JaxvaFX, SWT, or something else we don’t even know?

Comment: @Holger I use SWT indeed, thanks for the question, I edited original post ;)

Comment: SWT already looks at the display scaling and adjusts the sizes of everything. There is an `swt.autoScale` environment variable to give more control see for example [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Notes/article.html#hdpi-support-in-eclipse-4-6) and [here](https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php#swt-autoscale-tweaks)

Comment: @greg-449 I tested those, it handles everything but the font unfortunately

Comment: It all works fine on macOS at 200%, I don't use Windows so I don't know if there is some issue there.

Comment: on Windows, only buttons and images would be scaled, font would stay the same, at least on my app. Plus, I tried downscaling (because I want to restablish the original normal '100%' size, but it seems like ```swt.autoscale``` allows me only in 100% steps (100%, 200%; 300%...)

in the end, not finding a solution on my original question, I hacked swt in my app by changing default Shell font. Not perfect, but fits the need until I find better